С помощью чего и как можно переделать драйвер Windows x86 (.sys .dll) без исходников, под x64? Пусть без подписи
Может есть какие то специализированные утилиты для этого?
Если нет, подскажите с помощью чего можно sys и dll драйверов разобрать в с/с++ и как затем собрать в x64?

Никак. Мы использовали виртуалку с windows 7 32 для запуска таких драйверов, а потом расшаривали устройство по сети.
Если это принтер, то можно через виртуалку с линуксом (он компактнее) и расшарить по сети.
